# mkfs.xfs completely ignoring "|more" redirect

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pager, more

trying to install gentoo linux and can't format the drive with xfs because when I run `mkfs.xfs /dev/sda3` it throws an error and then displays help, but the help is so big that it takes up the entire screen and I can't scroll up because Im on tty1. `mkfs.xfs /dev/sda1 |more` does nothing, it still shows the enlarged help and doesn't pause. I've tried redirecting the output to a file using

```
cat mkfs.xfs /dev/sda1 > file.txt 2>&1
```

but it just outputs garbage

Comment: try `mkfs.xfs ... |& less`

Comment: Why do you have `cat` there: `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdX1 > file.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Install `tmux` or `screen` and run one of them as soon as you login on tty1, then you can use their scrollback features.    BTW, use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file.

Comment: It "just outputs garbage" because you've asked it to: `cat mkfs.xfs /dev/sda1` dumps the binary contents of the `mkfs.xfs` file (if it exists in the current directory) and of the `/dev/sda1` partition to the standard output.

Answer (score 3):

The `mkfs.xfs` command is likely following the convention of outputting diagnostic messages (errors and warnings etc.) to the standard error stream.  A pipe in the shell will only ever handle the standard *output* stream.  This is why piping the output of the command to `more` does not seem to work.

To pipe the errors from `mkfs.xfs` to `more`, you need to make sure that the error stream is redirected to the output stream before the pipe:

```bash
mkfs.xfs /dev/sda3 2>&1 | more
```

The `2>&1` thing means "redirect the 2nd stream (the error stream is always stream 2) to wherever the 1st stream (the output stream is always stream 1) is going.

Comment: note, in bash at least, you can also use `|&` which is shorthand for `2>&1 |` - (as per comment on the question)